# What is the difference between black box testing and end-to-end testing?

Tags: testing, end-to-end, black-box-testing

Both of them check the application from the user's point of view, so, what it's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the definitions of black box and end to end testing could vary based on the context of your project. I have seen different people use these terms to describe different things. That being said, usually this is what the 2 terms mean-

**Black box testing** - This refers to testing the system or the application as a black box where you give different inputs and expect a certain output without necessarily knowing the internals of the system. There are various techniques under this like equivalence class partition, decision table testing etc.

**End to end testing** - This refers to testing the system based on end to end user flows, instead of testing the system has separate components like in unit testing or story level testing. For example - Logging into the application, then adding a product to the shopping cart, then going to the check out screen and then placing an order and then logging out of the application could be one user flow.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about basics of testing like types of testing-black box, whitebox, grey box.

Black box testing is testing the application without going into code.

End to end testing is a type of black box testing in which we test application from a complete scenario point of view. A scenario can consists of many functionalities. Each of these functionality can have their own functional tests. Suppose user is shopping on a site then from searching an item and purchasing it is a complete end to end test i.e. searching an item then reading its description then adding to cart then ordering it is a end to end test.

While above end to end test contains many functionalities like searching, adding to cart etc. All these functionalities can have their own functional tests.

Both functional tests and end to end tests are black box tests.

You can also read [End to End tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378183/difference-between-system-testing-and-end-to-end-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Blackbox testing is the one, testing the application without looking in to the code or logics, basically pass an input and look for the expected output

End to End testing is the one, combination of the functional testing and non functional testing (Performance, Security, Reliability....)